# SQL query is slow: indexes?

Tags: php, sql, indexing

I have the following SQL query, but the query is very slow: (page loading 2 seconds).

```
mysql_query("select * from table_test 
WHERE ((owner = '$id' AND ownersecond = '0') OR ownersecond = '$id') 
AND catogory = '1' AND type = '$car[id]' AND caseB = '0' 
AND (timeback < TIMESTAMP(NOW()) OR timeback = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') ");
```

I want to improve the SQL statement by using indexes. I already have an index on the row: owner and owner second. Is it useful to put indexes on type, caseB and tieback? Or do i slow the sql more and more? Because of to many indexes?

Or: Is it better to rewrite above SQL into a faster query? And does anyone have a suggestion for a better written query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: you're likely open to SQL Injection.  You need to be using parameterized statements, or your database is going to get owned by automated tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing only on the query (and not the out-of-date mysql_ interface):

```
select *
from table_test 
WHERE ((owner = '$id' AND ownersecond = '0') OR ownersecond = '$id') AND
      catogory = '1' AND
      type = '$car[id]' AND
      caseB = '0' AND 
      timeback < TIMESTAMP(NOW()) OR timeback = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

An appropriate index is on `category`, `type`, `caseB`, and then the other columns.  So try this index:

```
create index idx_table_test_6 on table_test(category, type, caseB, timeback, owner, ownersecond)
```

The index can be used for all the `where` conditions, although the original data pages will be needed for the `select *`.

Comment: Worth noting that more indexes = longer write times.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution and it works on the current page: Page loading is much faster. 

Can you tell me this index affects other queries on other page, for example when i only do this at another page?


    select * from table_test where owner = $id and category = '1'     and type = '$car[id]'

Comment: You would need a different index for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to a diagnose what index is being used (if any). I recommend learning how to use EXPLAIN because it is difficult for us to recommend an additional index. If I were to take ***a guess***, I'd say that your `timeback` column requires an index, simply because a timestamp column is likely to be more varied than an `owner` column. Adding an index to every column will increase the time it takes to INSERT / UPDATE.